# Playground view output only shows black view

Tags: xcode, uikit, swift-playground, uistackview

I'm trying to take a selection of strings and display them in a `UIStackView` using `UILabel`s but I'm running into issues with them not displaying their text in my app. I created the following playground:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let standardFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480)
let stackView = UIStackView(frame: standardFrame)
stackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

let strings = ["Hello world", "Guten Tag", "Buenos Dias"]

strings.map { str in
    let newLabel = UILabel()
    newLabel.text = str
    return newLabel
}.forEach(stackView.addArrangedSubview)

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = stackView
```

In the assistant view I see a black box with the expected size, rather than blue with text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIStackView does not draw directly to the screen, it just sets up constraints for it's arranged subviews and has those subviews draw directly to the screen. It's background color is ignored because it doesn't draw itself to the screen. To get a background color, you can add it as a subview of a UIView.

Additionally, the text labels need to have their color set to something non-black since black text rendered over black background cannot be seen. The following code should create a nice UIStackView of white text on a blue background.

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let standardFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480)
let rootView = UIView(frame: standardFrame)
rootView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

let stackView = UIStackView(frame: standardFrame)
stackView.distribution = .EqualSpacing
stackView.alignment = .Center

let strings = ["Hello world", "Guten Tag", "Buenos Dias"]

strings.map { str in
    let newLabel = UILabel()
    newLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    newLabel.text = str
    return newLabel
    }.forEach(stackView.addArrangedSubview)

rootView.addSubview(stackView)
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = rootView
```